# Firemonkey Livebindings StringGrid (Grid) вставка компонентов в ячейки

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Пытаюсь для удобства пользователя вставить в `Grid` `CalendarEdit`.
Пока обдумываю 2 варианта:

1. Сделать так что бы во всех строчках были `CalendarEdit`.
   **Проблема**: *Создаю колонку необходимого формата*:

   ```
   TDateColumn = class(TColumn)
   protected
      function CreateCellControl: TStyledControl; override;
   end;
   function TDateColumn.CreateCellControl: TStyledControl;
   begin
      Result        := TDateCell.Create(grid);
      Result.Parent := grid;
   end;
   ```

   *добавляю её в* `Grid`:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   var
      cec: TDateColumn;
   begin
      cec:=TDateColumn.Create(grid1);
      grid1.AddObject(cec);
   end;
   ```

   всё показывает нормально. *Но при привязке при помощи* `liveBindings`:

   ```
   LinkGridToDataSource1.Columns.Items[LinkGridToDataSource1.Columns.Count-1].MemberName:='date';`
   ```

   компонент пропадает, и появляется обычная текстовая строка. Обнаружил что при `liveBindings` в **TLinkGridToDataSourceColumns** тип колонки еще раз указывается и там он стоит как Default, не пойму как туда добавить/создать нужный мне тип колонки.
2. Сделать что бы при клике на ячейку поверх неё отрисовывался контрол, а при клике в другое место пропадал и значение попадало в `Grid`.
   **Проблема**: не нашёл как можно определить координаты и размеры конкретной ячейки для отрисовки поверх неё.

Comment: Имхо если решил использовать Firemonkey, то нужно пилить первый метод, второй это уже костыли от безысходности. Хотелось бы посмотреть как реализовывал первый вариант, чтобы узнать в чем проблема.

Comment: Так и не решил этот вопрос и он всё еще актуален и сильно интересует меня. Вся загвоздка в том что TLinkGridToDataSourceColumns и его свойство ColumnStyle перезаписывает любой какой бы то ни было формат колонки Grid'а. А там всего 4 типа колонки - стринг, битмап, чекбокс, прогрессбар. Как прибиндивать к другим контролам в колонке инфы в Интернете нет...

Comment: Насчёт второго варианта, его осуществить НЕ получается по той же причине. После того как лайвбиндишь процедура ОнКлик перезаписывается этим компонентом TLinkGridToDataSourceColumns.

Comment: Я к тому, что хотелось бы проект посмотреть, так сразу и не скажешь, ньюансов много.

Comment: Отредактировал пост

Comment: UP! если тут так можно делать...